# Nginx config with envsubst quotes issue

Tags: docker, nginx

Docker entry file:

```
if
  [ ${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED} = "true" ];
then
  export BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED="Private site";
else
  export BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED=off;
fi

envsubst '${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED}' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I'm setting `BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED` var in a docker compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  site:
    restart: always
    image: "199.99.9.99:5000/site:dev"
    ports:
      - 8287:80
    environment:
      - BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED=true
```

Nginx complains: `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "auth_basic" directive`. If i use just `"Private"`, then it works. What do i miss?

**UPDATE 1**

default.conf:

```
location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  auth_basic ${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED};
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what the specific lines in `default.conf` look like after the substitution? This might give a hint where to dig deeper.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] with the default.conf file.

Comment: @bellackn, i can't check, because container won't start with this kind of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this to be a quoting issue. Here is a shot in the dark:

Nginx's config line in question needs *one* string argument, and this is what it gets when you use `"Private"`. After the substitution, the line in the config file will look like this:

```
auth_basic Private;
```

All good, one argument.

If you use `"Private site"` instead, it will look like this after the substitution:

```
auth_basic Private site;
```

So, there are basically two string arguments, because there are no quotes. Try to adapt your script to something like this:

```
export BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED='"Private site"';
```

This should lead to:

```
auth_basic "Private site";
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks. Also updated my post with default.conf

Comment: It's indeed was quoting issue, thank you, vm. By this opportunity i want to ask one more thing: `envsubst '${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED}' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` what for there's "> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" ? To the left it applies env variable and substitutes inside nginx config, but what does right chevron?

Comment: If it wasn't for the `>`, `envsubst` would output the substituted `default.conf` to `stdout`. The `>` redirects it to a file, which in this case has the same name, so it just overwrites it.